# Attaching an ical file to a django email

Tags: django, django-email

There are plenty of examples of how to attach a file to an email, but I can't find an example of how to attach a MIMEBase instance.

From the docs: attachments "These can be either email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase instances, or (filename, content, mimetype) triples."

So I'm generating an iCal file in a function just fine:

```
def ical()
    cal = vobject.iCalendar()
    cal.add('method').value = 'PUBLISH'  # IE/Outlook needs this

    vevent = cal.add('vevent')
    vevent.add('dtstart').value = self.course.startdate
    vevent.add('dtend').value = self.course.startdate
    vevent.add('summary').value='get details template here or just post url'
    vevent.add('uid').value=str(self.id)
    vevent.add('dtstamp').value = self.created

    icalstream = cal.serialize()
    response = HttpResponse(icalstream, mimetype='text/calendar')
    response['Filename'] = 'shifts.ics'  # IE needs this
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=shifts.ics'
    return response
```

But this is not working:

```
   myicalfile = ical()
   message.attach(myicalfile)
```

Comment: How exactly is myicalfile variable created? Is it really an email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase instance?

Comment: Have edit to make it clearer where myicalfile comes from and no it is not an emailMIMEBase as I am not clear how to make one!

Comment: did you try 'HttpResponse(icalstream, content_type='text/calendar')' instead of 'mimetype'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code at the end of def ical():

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
part = MIMEText(icalstream,'calendar')
part.add_header('Filename','shifts.ics') 
part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename=shifts.ics') 
return part
```

Of course, the import code should be moved at the top of file to conform with coding standards.

Comment: how can i send this to particular email address?